# Unable to start cassandra : Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM)

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to start a cassandra container using docker-compose . I am issueing the following command from my macbook terminal.

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/cassandra.yml up
```

my cassandra.yml file is below

```
version: '2'
services:
    primecast-cassandra:
        image: cassandra:3.9
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/primecast/cassandra/:/var/lib/cassandra/data
        ports:
            - 7000:7000
            - 7001:7001
            - 7199:7199
            - 9042:9042
            - 9160:9160
    primecast-cassandra-migration:
        extends:
            file: cassandra-migration.yml
            service: primecast-cassandra-migration
        environment:
            - CREATE_KEYSPACE_SCRIPT=create-keyspace.cql
```

However when i run the  docker-compose command to start the cassandra services i get some warning on the terminal & eventually it stops.

```
    primecast-cassandra_1            | WARN  14:33:45 Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). 

This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled.  Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
```

appreciate if you can help
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, this message is telling you that you need to specify `memlock unlimited` for the Linux system resource limit on the locked-in memory for a specific user.  As per the [documentation on recommended production settings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html), the normal (non-Docker) way to solve for this was to adjust the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file (or equivalent) as such:

```
cassandra - memlock unlimited
```

In the above example, `cassandra` is the user that Cassandra is running under.  If you're running Cassandra as another user, you'll need to either change that accordingly or just use asterisk (*) to enforce that setting for all users.  Ex:

```
* - memlock unlimited
```

In this case with [Docker Compose v2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ulimits), `ulimits` should be a valid entry under the service configuration.  Set `memlock` to `-1` so that both the soft and hard limits are "unlimited":

```
primecast-cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.9
    ulimits:
        memlock: -1
    ports:
```